# Script running fine on debug mode but not in run mode in selenium

Tags: eclipse, selenium

Here is my script

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tb_pg1']/tr[6]/td[1]/input[1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='afn_inventory']/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/button")).click();
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//button[@name='Continue to shipping plan']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@name='Continue to shipping plan']")).click();
```

Comment: What do you mean running fine in debug mode but not in run mode?? is there any exception?? in which line have you problem??

Comment: Last line of the code (click on the button) is run on debug mode but not in run mode. though, this the exception "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='batch-update-number-cases']"}" but works fine on debug mode. Last link click the button is problem.

Comment: But this line is not mentioned in your provided code. When line execute??

Comment: do you mean this line `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[@name='Continue to shipping plan']")).click();` does not click to the element?? thats why next line throws `NuSuchElementException`??